# How to make ui full screen with transparent status bar in android sdk 30 use setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)

Tags: android, kotlin, fullscreen, statusbar, transparent

Before I use

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = 
(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or 
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
 View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR)
```

But in api 30 is deprecated.

I try to use setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false), it is work, full screen with transparent status bar but my bottom navigation view is show under the naviation bar ,like this photo.

[image: photo]

How to fix it?? Thanks

Comment: check out [WindowInsets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsets.html)

Comment: did you mean get navigation height and set margin bottom ??
@AskNilesh

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_mGDMVRO3iE